# String queries in BreezeJS that contain single or double quotes return error

Tags: breeze

I have a text input for a search field where the string is then passed to an EntityQuery. When ever the query includes a single quote I get a message like the following:

There is an unterminated string literal at position 39 in 'substringof(O'Malley,FirstName) eq true'.

It even happens when just hard coding the query like this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
                .from("Users")
                .expand("GroupUsers.Group")
                .where("lastName", "contains","O'Malley")
                .skip(skipAmt)
                .take(pageSize)
                .inlineCount(true);
```

I've tried escaping the single quote by doing double single quotes or doing \' and it still comes back with an error. This also happens similarly with double quotes. What is the proper way to escape the string literal characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't repro this.  You should be able to escape a single ' by simply doubling it.  For example, the following query works without a problem on **v 1.2.8**.

```
 var q = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
        .where("lastName", "contains", "O''Malley");
```

Does the problem still occur if you 'simplify' the query down to just the where 'clause'?

Comment: This works for me. I was mistaken when trying to escape it with doubling single quotes. Now when the query string comes in I just run `filterText = filterText.replace(/'/g, "''")`

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered a bug in breeze? I would've expected it to handle escaping for me.

Comment: The next version 1.4.8 will do exactly this.  It should be out in about a week.